# Convert float to Decimal with fixed digits after decimal

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I want to convert some `floats` to `Decimal` retaining 5 digits after decimal place regardless of how many digits before the decimal place.  Is using string formatting the most efficient way to do this?

I see in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html):

> The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations.

So that means I need to add 0 to force it to use the specified `prec` but the `prec` is total digits not after decimal so it doesn't actually help.

The best thing I can come up with is

```
a=[1.132434, 22.2334,99.33999434]
[Decimal("%.5f" % round(x,5)) for x in a]
```

to get `[Decimal('1.13243'), Decimal('22.23340'), Decimal('99.33999')]`

Is there a better way?  It *feels* like turning floats into strings just to convert them back to a number format isn't very good although I can't articulate why.

Comment: If you're truly OK with losing precision, then the way you're doing it is the best way to control the number of digits in the `Decimal` instances created.

Comment: Why the `round` call?

Comment: "need to add 0 to force it" - The doc suggests unary plus.

Comment: @KellyBundy well my example doesn't illustrate this since all of the 6th digits are less than 5 but I wouldn't want 99.339997 to be *just* truncated to 99.33999 but rather be rounded to 99.34000

Comment: I get [99.34000 without `round`](https://tio.run/##ZYvLCsIwEEX3@YqhUEigBJpp0Szc9S9KF8EaDJgHQwrx61PRutHdPZdz0jPfY8BzolotRQ/r7eq8eYDzKVKG6YPMXOZe9qgGHDpQSip8Da0lotb6fX7htLBELmTO5iPmTStH20ALFLew8tKNQoCNBAVcALOIo/gPyo9X6w4). Do you not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do all the formatting on the way out from your code, inside the `print` and `write` statements. There is no reason I can think of to lose precision (and convert the numbers to some fixed format) while doing numeric calculations inside the code.

Comment: You might want to "lose" *imprecision*, though. Since `1.132434` doesn't have the value 1.132434. Just like `0.1` doesn't have the value 0.1, so if you for example repeatedly multiply by 11 and subtract 1, which should get you back to 0.1, you might end up with [140892568471739.25](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v0LBVsFAz5CroCgzr0SjQpMrLb9IIV4hM0@hKDEvPVXD2EDTiksBCEAKDQ0VtIAMXQVDsBBMz///AA) instead.

Comment: @KellyBundy perhaps this is to Timur's point, but if you replace your `x=0.1` with `x=Decimal("0.1")` then it works as expected/hoped.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Not sure what you mean. Your question is about converting a float. And `"0.1"` is not a float but a string.